# Increase Azure Database DTU in range of hours

Tags: database, azure, io, cpu, data-access

i have a system who uses database of Azure and in the morning(6h~12h) the access is too high, DTU arrive to 100%, but the rest of the day DTU stabilizes in 20%.
I want to known if have a way that i can schedule to increase DTU only in the morning, if i duplicate DTU for the entire day will be expensive for me.

If have other ways to do this, please help me ;)
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jonathan, which pricing tier are you on?

Comment: Just the Database i pay $75, if i duplicate for the entire day  i will pay $150